# In @Ajax.ActionLink html style isn't work MVC, AJAX.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have newxt Ajax.ActionLink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Добавить",
        "CreatPlayer",
        null,
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "view-creating-form",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        },
        new
        {
            @class = "toggle-tab"
        }
    )
```

and for him the css styles

```
css styles.toggle-tab {
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: black;
}
```

the problem is the styles doesn't work, a take in result usual link style. How fix it and what a problem?[Don't see css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrYN.png)

Comment: try to remove name prefix `css styles` from your css so it becomes => `.toggle-tab {
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: black;
}`

Comment: doesn't help, i add a picture which show that the css not display html code

Comment: where this css comes from? From stylesheet file or from inline css.

Comment: If its comes from stylesheet file then make sure you referenced file present on that location and all css classes imported successfully or if it comes from inline css then make sure you write these classes on top of your view with `<style>...</style>` element

Comment: no problem with css file decause other elements work with css styles
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Admin.css"/>

Comment: inspect your actionlink in browser and copy rendered html here

Comment: interesting situation i clear my history with cookie, it's help me 
but how link css with history in browser

Comment: After clearing cookies and history, your problem solved right? I think deep refresh `Ctrl + F5` will also help you instead of clearing cookies and history.

Comment: it's stupid but help, really don't understand this situation, and thank you for helping